# Formatting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Is there a way to restart my OS (18.04.1) as if I had just installed it (it's a partition) without having to uninstall it and installing it again??

I mean, like to format the computer and start over with all the default settings.

I did something to the bash and, though everything seems to work there are done small details that annoy me.

Comment: What is annoying you about your bash settings? Might be easier to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

You may not have to reinstall. First thing is to ascertain what you did to your bash and if it was system wide or just for your user ID.

Create a new user ID and see if it works normally. If so there is no damage done to 18.04 just for your old user ID.

Ubuntu keeps a "skeleton" of most configurations that get copied to when a new user ID is created. For `.bashrc` it is in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`:

```
$ llocate .bashrc
ACCESS      OWNER  GROUP  SIZE  MODIFIED      NAME (updatdb last ran: 2018-10-06 10:30:06)
-rw-r--r--  root   root   2188  Aug 31  2015  /etc/bash.bashrc
-rw-r--r--  root   root   3771  Aug 31  2015  /etc/skel/.bashrc
-rw-r--r--  rick   rick   7522  Sep 30 10:10  /home/rick/.bashrc
-rw-r--r--  rick   rick   7492  Sep 30 10:09  /home/rick/.bashrc~
```

**If** you modified `.bashrc` and damaged it there **may** be a backup called `.bashrc~` which you can copy over top.

Answer (score 0):

First backup all data and install the OS over 18.04 again using bootable USB or something like that

Comment: That's overkill.